# Git understanding behaviour of checkout branch and presence and absence of files

Tags: git, git-checkout

Variation of this question have been asked and answered but I am still perplexed as I work my way thru the Chacon book.

I have cloned my test repository from github.
I created a file in this called afile.txt that I stage and commit
I created a 2nd file in this called asecondfile.txt that I don't stage or commit

Now I execute

```
$ git checkout -b testing
Switched to a new branch 'testing'
```

When I list the files, I see only asecondfile.txt.

I make a change to this file, don't stage or commit and execute

```
$ git checkout master
```

If I cat asecondfile.txt I can see the changes I made in testing branch.

```
$ git checkout testing
```

I stage and commit the changes to asecondfile.txt.

```
$ git checkout master
```

I list files I don't see aseconfile.txt.

Really puzzled by this behavior and would be glad of an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When a file is neither staged nor committed, git doesn't know anything about it.  Such a path is called "untracked".  Git leaves these alone, but gripes about them being "untracked" when you run `git status`.  (You can shut up the griping, but ignore that until you get to `.gitignore`.)

Once a file is staged, though, it's no longer "untracked".  It's now a tracked file (and adding it to `.gitignore` won't help, it's already tracked). Once that tracked file is committed git knows to *remove* it when switching from a commit that has it—such as the commit you just made on `testing`—to a commit that doesn't.

This is what you saw: `git checkout master` removed the file, because it's committed (and therefore also in the index/staging-area) when you're on branch `testing`, and the commit that is the tip of branch `master` does *not* have that file.

Once git has removed it (by switching to `master`), the path is no longer staged nor committed, so if you create a new `asecondfile.txt` *after* switching to `master`, that's an "untracked" file.  If you then ask git to `git checkout testing` it should complain and fail by default: it would have to remove your untracked file, so as to replace it with a tracked file with (presumably) different contents.

Comment: Well said. Also read: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: After reading your response it helps me to visualize the working area as being "common" across branches.  If I make changes to a file in one branch and don't commit, an attempt to switch to another branch- where a different, committed, version of the file exists, fails because the working area is going to get overlaid.

Richard- that's the very chapter I'm making heavy weather of :)

Comment: @torek Your answer is missing something important - in your second paragraph you noted that the file was staged but in the 3rd paragraph you said it had been committed.  I think you forgot to add a line that indicated that the file was committed after it was staged.  (This would certainly confuse a git newcomer and should be clarified.)  I'll make the edit.  Additionally in that second paragraph you said, "Now that it's tracked, git knows to remove it when switching from a commit that has it..." - that is completely incorrect.  That behavior is only the case once the file is committed.